# Visual studio line colors

Tags: visual-studio, colors

In Visual Studio, what does the vertical color bar between the line numbers and the code mean?
Sometimes there is green, yellow, or nothing.

Comment: This feature is called "Track Changes"  under Text Editor > General ... in case you want to enable or disable it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Nothing means no changes.

Green means saved changes. These will disappear when the file is closed and reopened.

Bright yellow means unsaved changes. These change to green when the file is saved.

Dark yellow means unsaved undos (i.e. you've made and edit and then hit Ctrl+Z). These disappear when the file is saved.

Comment: The scroll margin (right side) also shows bookmarks (white(or grey?)) peeks(blue) errors(red) and breaks(red).

Answer (score 11):

The line indicates changes to code since last save.

- No color = no change
- Yellow = Track changes before save
- Green = Track changes after save

Comment: If you go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors, in the enormous list of all the possible colors, meanings provided by the answer is exactly how they called in the settings window. Available to customize by user needs.