# Green and Yellow bar near line numbers

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual studio, sometimes the `color bars (green, yellow)` displayed near to the line numbers.

what is the meaning of the color bars?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009334/visual-studio-line-colors. It's a old post, but still applies to latest version.

Comment: Yes... Thanks... Sometimes some of the developers have the time to ask question and don't have time to check all the suggested question from the list... So duplicate question occurs...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check [Options, Text Editor, General](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e19z9c39.aspx) -> Track changes

> Track changes
>
> When the code editor is selected, a vertical yellow line appears in the selection margin to mark code that has changed since the file was most recently saved. When you save the changes, the vertical lines become green.

Alternative link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efc4xwkb.aspx. Open it and search 'Change Tracking'.

Comment: Thanks. You saved my life, because every time I select lines, it opens that annoying git changes. So finally I managed to disable it.